# How do I create a copy of a file in multiple directories?

Tags: find, cp, exec

I have a folder structure

```
conf/
    widget1/
        env1.cfg
        env2.cfg
    widget2/
        env1.cfg
        env2.cfg
    widget3/
        env1.cfg
        env2.cfg
    widget4/
        env1.cfg
        env2.cfg
    ...
```

What I want to do is find all the files named `env2.cfg`, and create a copy of them in their directory named `env3.cfg`.

I've tried:

```
find -name env2.cfg -exec cp '{}' "env3.cfg" ";"
```

but that just created `env3.cfg` in the `conf/` directory.

Any thoughts?

For clarification I'm doing this on Mac OSX, but ideally the same command should work on CentOS if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`find . -name env2.cfg -execdir cp {} env3.cfg \;`

By replacing `exec` to `execdir`. It will mean that your 'action' (`cp`) will take place inside the folder where the file (`env2.cfg`) have been found.

Comment: Does the Mac's `find` have the excellent `-execdir`?

Comment: Sure, it does :)

Answer (score 2):

Your example copies all env2.cfg files to the current working directory, which is ".". You need to give the file found a new name, including its directory. This one worked for me:

```
for file in $(find . -name env2.cfg); do backup=$(echo $file | sed 's/env2.cfg/env3.cfg/'); cp $file $backup; done
```

edit:
Or the even more elegant way, so you don't have to bother with multiple commands:

```
for file in $(find . -name env2.cfg); do cp $file ${file/env2/env3}; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a static structure you can directly address the filenames and let the shell copy them:

```
for f in conf/widget*/env2.cfg
do
    cp "${f}" "${f/env2/env3}"
done
```